# Why echo Off and syntax error is there for my code

Tags: batch-file

This is my code using to run batch script to run SQL script and generating execution log. Help me to understand

```
::Echo off will hide all commands written in text file
@echo off

    :: Declaring colour appearance of the batch
    color Af
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

    ::Declaration of the SQL Server Name.
    set  servername=192.168.90.34

    :: Declaration of the source path where we will keep script file.
    set  spath=D:\Batch_Test_File\Script_File

    ::Declaration of the destination Path where we will move script file after successful execution.
    set  dpath=D:\Batch_Test_File\Executed_script\Enterprise_Script

        :: Creation of the Execution log folder basis of current date.
        set TIMESTAMP=%DATE:~7,2%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~10,4%
        IF EXIST "%D:\Batch_Test_File\Execution_log\%TIMESTAMP%" (
            echo Folder exist
            set  lpath=D:\Batch_Test_File\Execution_log\%TIMESTAMP%
            echo %lpath%
            ) ELSE (
            md "%D:\Batch_Test_File\Execution_log\%TIMESTAMP%"
            set  lpath=D:\Batch_Test_File\Execution_log\%TIMESTAMP%
            echo %lpath%
        )

    :: Declaration of the credential of the SQL Server 2008
    set  uname=sa
    set  pwd=sa@gr8

    :: Defining Flag for capturing error status of script file
    set temp=0
    echo temp value1:-%temp%

    :: Printing ServerName on Which script will apply.
    echo Server_Name:-%servername%

    :: Printing Source path of the script file
    echo File_Path:-%spath%
    pause

    :: Listing all files from Source Path
    set cmd='dir %spath%\*ED*.sql /b/s'
    echo %cmd%
    pause

    ::Creating Log file basis of script file available



    ::Taken a loop as per the count of file in CMD Variable
    FOR /f "delims=" %%G IN (%cmd%) DO (
    echo inside loop
    set _fn=%%G
    set _fn=!_fn:~31,11!
    set logfilepath= %lpath%\output_!_fn!.log
    echo %logfilepath%--Here echo is off coming. If Using echo !logfilepath! then it is printing but not able to capture log further
    echo logfilepath1 file name here
    pause
        FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A in  (D:\Batch_Test_File\EnterpriseDatabaseList.txt) do (
            echo Database_Name:- %%A >> %logfilepath%---here throwing syntax error
            echo ******PROCESSING %%G FILE******
            SQLCMD -S%servername% -U %uname% -P %pwd%  -d %%A -b -i%%G >> %logfilepath%
            echo %%G File
            echo Database_Name:- %%A >> %logfilepath%
            IF !ERRORLEVEL! EQU 0 echo ******PROCESSED %%G FILE****** >> %logfilepath%
            IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 echo ******NOT PROCESSED %%G FILE****** >> %logfilepath%
            IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 set /a temp+=1
            echo SQL SERVER ERROR:- !ERRORLEVEL! 
        )
    MOVE %%G %dpath% 
    )
::pause
echo temp value2:-%temp%
pause
IF %temp% EQU 0 GOTO Success IF NOT GOTO :OnError

:OnError
echo ERROR ERROR ERROR
echo One\more script(s) failed to execute, terminating path.
echo Check output.log file for more details
echo File not moved  >> %logfilepath%
pause
EXIT /b

:Success
echo ALL the scripts deployed successfully!! >> %logfilepath%
pause
EXIT /b
```

Please help me on this!

Answer (score 1):

You are using `echo %lpath%` within the same brackets that you're setting lpath in.

If you either use `echo !lpath!` to use delayed expansion (which you have set) or simply echo after the `if () else ()`

Likewise for logfilepath. Which is also why you're getting the syntax error as the echo lines become:

```
echo Database_Name:- %%A >> 
echo ******PROCESSING %%G FILE******
SQLCMD -S%servername% -U %uname% -P %pwd%  -d %%A -b -i%%G >>
```

You need to be using `>> !logfilepath!`

Comment: I have tried with !logfilepath! to capture result..but it is showing syntax error. And my problem is occurring on below code
FOR /f "delims=" %%G IN (%cmd%) DO (
    echo inside loop
    set _fn=%%G
    set _fn=!_fn:~31,11!
    set logfilepath= %lpath%\output_!_fn!.log
    echo %logfilepath%--Here echo is off coming. If Using echo !logfilepath! then it is printing but not able to capture log further
    echo logfilepath1 file name here

Comment: @user3906232 As ScottC said: Replace your `%lpath%` and `%logfilepath%` with `!lpath!` and `!logfilepath!`

Comment: lpath is only folder location..logfilepath is the file where i need to capture result

Comment: OK, 2 other errors you need to fix. 1. `"%D:\Batc...` should just be `"D:\Batc...` (no % before the d:)  2 `set logfilepath= %lpat...` should be `set logfilepath=%lpat...` (no space after equals)